# Log-In Code Doesn't Work

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication

**Hi!** The objective of this code is to log-in to a website. *This code has no error* but still doesn't redirect to a profile page. Please, help. Thank you!

```
<?php

include("dbconnect.php");
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "post")
{
$username = $_POST['student'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query=mysqli_query($dbconfig,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE sn=$username AND pw=$password");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count==1)
{
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username;

header("location: main.php");
}
else
{
$error="Username or Password is invalid";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Also use exit after header  `header("location: main.php");exit;`

Comment: Change `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'post'` to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`. Note that `POST` is uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write you query like this

```
 $query=mysqli_query($dbconfig,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE sn='".$username."' AND pw='".$password."'");
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is it showing any errors?

Comment: No error. Nothing happens when I input username and password. The webpage reloads.

Comment: put your html form code in question

Comment: Thank you very much! I've found out the problem. I haven't assigned the a user to the database. Thanks and sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't work. Try with `SELECT * FROM members WHERE sn='$username' AND pw='$password'`

And also after you execute the query check if the are some errors with

```
if(!$query)
 die(mysqli_error($dbconfig));
```

P.S. sanitize username and password before inserting them in a query

Comment: Thank you very much! I've found out the problem. I haven't assigned the a user to the database. Thanks and sorry!